# jquery multiple selectors in single query

Tags: html, jquery, dom

I have various lists and inside those lists I've list of checkboxes and I've show more/less functionality.

Now, everything works fine but I want to convert some logic to one liner, tried various ways but didn't work so posting here.

Here is HTML part, and assume I have multiple lists like this.

```
<div id="list-special-needs">
    <h4 class="filter-header">Special Needs</h4>

    @foreach (var item in specialNeeds)
    {
        <div class="am-checkbox" style="padding: 3px 0;">
            <input id="chk-special-needs-@item.ToLower()" name="special-needs" value="@item" type="checkbox" class="schedulerepeat-checkbox" onclick="return prepareSearchParams()" />
            <label for="chk-special-needs-@item.ToLower()" class="margin-h-10 mobile-padding">@item</label>
        </div>
    }

    <p onclick="return loadMore(this, 'list-special-needs', '@specialNeeds.Length')" class="show-more">Show more...</p>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    PageEvent.add(PageEvent.AFTER_INIT, function () {
        $("#list-services .am-checkbox").slice(5).hide();
        $("#list-timing .am-checkbox").slice(5).hide();
        $("#list-special-needs .am-checkbox").slice(5).hide();        
        $("#list-neighborhoods .am-checkbox").slice(5).hide();
    });

    function loadMore(element, listId, length) {
        var listSelector = $(`#${listId} .am-checkbox`);
        var isShowMore = $(element).text() == 'Show more...';

        if (isShowMore) {
            //..show more
            $(element).text('Hide...');
            listSelector.slice(0, length).slideDown();

        } else {
            //..hide
            $(element).text('Show more...');
            listSelector.slice(5).slideUp();
        }
    }
</script>
```

and I just want to convert this into one liner.

```
$("#list-services .am-checkbox").slice(5).hide();
$("#list-timing .am-checkbox").slice(5).hide();
$("#list-special-needs .am-checkbox").slice(5).hide();        
$("#list-neighborhoods .am-checkbox").slice(5).hide();
```

Although I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
$("#list-services .am-checkbox, #list-timing .am-checkbox ..").slice(5).hide();
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with each one of them separately. So from your code:

```
$("#list-services .am-checkbox, #list-timing .am-checkbox ..").slice(5).hide();
```

We can take that and loop through and attack each one with

```
Array.from($("#list-services .am-checkbox, #list-timing .am-checkbox ..")).forEach(elem => {elem.slice(5).hide());
```

Although I'd suggest adding a class to each one of the blocks with te `list-...` IDs, so the code is nicer and go with:

```
Array.from($(".list-block .am-checkbox")).forEach(elem => {elem.slice(5).hide());
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding a class: then it will not serve the purpose. using id, I can target specific list and show more/less. if I use class, it will not work that way. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: sure, but it depends. If you have, let's say, 3 options, then you can add 3 classes to them and target by each one. Just example `class="clients admin guest"` for one and `class="clients admin"` for the other. And you use either class in the JS according to your use case.

Comment: got your point, so just instead of id, it will be a class. but will it have any positive impact?

Comment: you can add multiple classes to the same element to match different use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Create array of your elements with id's, then for each search for that same class and do stuff...

```
[...$("#list-services"), ...$("#list-timing"), ...$("#list-special-needs"), ...$("#list-neighborhoods")].forEach(el => {
  $(el).find(".am-checkbox").slice(5).hide()
})
```

*"need something more elegant"*

*Beauty is in eye of the beholder*, is this one pretty enough?

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("#list-services, #list-timing, #list-special-needs, #list-neighborhoods")].forEach(el => $(el).find(".am-checkbox").slice(5).hide())
```

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("#list-services, #list-timing, #list-special-needs, #list-neighborhoods")].forEach(el => $(el).find(".am-checkbox").css("color", "red"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list-services">
  <div class="am-checkbox">1</div>
</div>

<div id="list-timing">
  <div class="am-checkbox">2</div>
</div>
<div id="list-special-needs">
  <div class="am-checkbox">3</div>
</div>
<div id="list-neighborhoods">
  <div class="am-checkbox">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: looks good, but need something more elegant.

Comment: ikik, your solution worked properly with few modifications I did. thanks!